# Split Voltage Rectifier Blowing Fuses

Tags: power, rectifier, split

I had somebody bring in some equipment for repair and the fuse on the -32v rail of the supply was blown.  I checked the current at the junction of both of the 4.7 ohm 5W resisters and the positive side was showing 0.32A and the Negative was showing 2A which explains the blown fuse (1.6A fuse)  I tested the D8 and D12-14 and all were functioning.  Any idea what would be causing the current to be so big on the negative rail?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i know this sounds obvious but a piece of debris somewhere creating a short, a TIN bridge caused by aging tin, or a broken electrolytic Capacitor.  maybe see if some component warms up.

Comment: How was the fuse blown? If the wire is balled then there was an overload. If the wire is broken, it could be mechanical stress caused it to fail. Each time the power is cycled, there’s the inrush current that stresses the wire.,Rinse and repeat many times and the wire fails mechanically.